# PHP file_get_contents not working correctly

Tags: php, json, function, fopen, file-get-contents

I asked a question on here yesterday and was given the following code.

```
<?php 

        function usd_rate(){
        $json = file_get_contents("https://bitpay.com/api/rates");
            $obj = json_decode($json);
                if($obj->code == 'USD') return $o->rate;    
        }
        echo usd_rate()
?>
```

It worked fine at first, but I left my shared hosting and moved to a dedicated server host.

I have checked the PHP.ini to ensure the below

```
; Whether to allow the treatment of URLs (like http:// or ftp://) as files.
; http://php.net/allow-url-fopen
allow_url_fopen = On

; Whether to allow include/require to open URLs (like http:// or ftp://) as fil$
; http://php.net/allow-url-include
allow_url_include = On
```

but it still doesnt show any of the values. I have been stuck on this for about 2 hours now so I thought it might be a wise idea to ask for help.

Thanks for any you can provide me.

Also

Output of `php --version`

```
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.4 (cli) (built: Sep  4 2014 06:56:34)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

Not sure what my last host was running

Comment: `error_reporting(-1)`? Apache error logs?

Comment: try $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'api/rates' like this..

Comment: Have you restarted your webserver after making php.ini changes?

Comment: yeah restarted whole machine infacte, When I do a var_dump on the json object it shows the data "array(158) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1 (3) { ["code"]=> string(3) "USD" ["name"]=> string(9) "US Dollar" ["rate"]=> float(471.76) }", I want to get the ['rate'] but when I try to get it, it just shows as blank, maybe im missing something (I am new to PHP :()

Answer (score 2):

there is error in code u have given try this code

```
function usd_rate(){
    $json = file_get_contents("https://bitpay.com/api/rates");
    $obj = json_decode($json);
    foreach($obj as $o) 
        if($o->code == 'USD') return $o->rate;    
}
echo usd_rate();
```